# Should you ever use local inner functions?

Tags: javascript, function

Which of these is normally seen as better when writing JavaScript. Foo, bar, and baz are specific to this function so won't be used anywhere else in other functions.

```
function() {
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}

function foo() {
    //lines of code
}

function bar() {
    //lines of code
}

function baz() {
    //lines of code
}
```

Or

```
function() {
    function foo() {
        //lines of code
    }
    foo();
    function bar() {
        //lines of code
    }
    bar();
    function baz() {
        //lines of code
    }
    baz();
}
```

The advantages of the first is it is more efficient since if you are calling the function more that once the other functions only need to be created once. It is also easier to read as the main outer function is now only 3 lines long and not much longer.

The only advantage I can think for the second is it keeps these functions private to the outer function and not accessible to the rest of the file which is good since these functions will not be used anywhere else. Obviously normally making things public when they shouldn't need to be is bad but is that less important in JavaScript situations like this.

Is it possible you would choose differently depending on how often the function was called or anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you want all functions to be publicly available by themselves, declare them separately

  ```
  function foo() {} // Public, created once
  function bar() {} // Public, created once
  function baz() {} // Public, created once
  var fooBarBaz = function() { // Public, created once
    foo(); bar(); baz();
  };
  ```
- If you want the auxiliary functions to be able to access the scope of the main function, with the trade-of that they will have to be recreated each time you call the main function, place the auxiliary function inside the main one

  ```
  var fooBarBaz = function() { // Public, created once
    function foo() {} // Private, created at each fooBarBaz call
    function bar() {} // Private, created at each fooBarBaz call
    function baz() {} // Private, created at each fooBarBaz call
    foo(); bar(); baz();
  };
  ```
- If you want to keep the auxiliary functions private, and you don't want to recreate them each time you call the main function, use an IIFE

  ```
  var fooBarBaz = (function() { // IIFE
    function foo() {} // Private, created once
    function bar() {} // Private, created once
    function baz() {} // Private, created once
    return function() { // Public, created once
      foo(); bar(); baz();
    };
  })();
  ```

Comment: Why do you declare only the fooBarBaz function with `var`? Is that just to parallel the IIFE example where it has to be done that way?

Comment: you haven't really answered my question, just repeated it. I already stated the advantages and disadvantages, I'm more asking for the general situation described above which one of these categories does it fall into?

Comment: The middle one is only worthwhile if `fooBarBaz` is called one time, so I would highlight that it shouldn't be used. The IIFE is most recommended, and it's what the OP should use.

Comment: When it is a 'trade-off' between not wanting your functions to be public available but wanting your function to be short and easy to read what is the best-practice JavaScript?

Comment: @user2802557 The answer is to choose both a go with the (IMO highly readable) IIFE. This is such a common pattern that many people will know what it's doing when they see it.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I used `var` to parallel the IIFE

Comment: @4castle The middle approach can be useful if you want the auxiliary function to read the arguments of the main function, and the main function uses the auxiliary functions instead of calling them. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9qufhuoq/)

Comment: @user2802557 You asked "should you ever use local inner functions". My answer says in which case you should use them. And I also included the IIFE approach, which is some kind of a mix.

Comment: What if each of the foo, bar, baz contain inner functions of their own which then also contains inner functions. We will end up with a nested mess which is very hard to follow. This is avoided the other way.